# Jersey - Pojo communication works, getEtntity doesnt

Tags: http, rest, jersey, pojo

I used [this](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#client-api) chapter 4.3 for communicating with pojos in my rest service. At the moment I can post and get the pojo. It works fine. But when I try to get the entity of my response I get this exception:

```
 27.06.2012 10:44:44 com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse getEntity
 SCHWERWIEGEND: A message body reader for Java class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement, and  Java type class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement, and MIME media type application/xml was not found
 27.06.2012 10:44:44 com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse getEntity
 SCHWERWIEGEND: The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
 application/xml ->
```

On server side I wrap the entity like this:

```
  res = Response.created(UriBuilder.fromUri(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + object.getObjectId()).build()).entity(new JAXBElement<ObjectPOJO>(new QName("objectpojo"), ObjectPOJO.class, object)).build();
```

I tried it as well with just wrapping the pojo without JAXBElement.

On client side I tried different approaches:

```
 GenericType<JAXBElement<ObjectPOJO>> objectType = new GenericType<JAXBElement<ObjectPOJO>>() {};
 objectType = (GenericType<JAXBElement<ObjectPOJO>>) res.getEntity(JAXBElement.class).getValue();

 object = res.getEntity(ObjectPOJO.class);
```

and so on. Does anyone know whats the right approach? Like I said, the get and post communication works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
ObjectPOJO object = res.getEntity(new GenericType<JAXBElement<ObjectPOJO>>() {}).getValue();
```

Comment: Thanks mate, u helped me a lot in the past. One mistake: it should be getValue()